# Adding fractions using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, fractions

I need to write a recursive method to compute the following series:

```
m(i) = 1/3 + 2/5 + 3/7 + 4/9 + 5/11 + 6/13 + .... + i/(2i + 1)
```

Then I need to write a program that displays `m(i)` for `i = 1,2,....10`.

I understand the basic idea of recursion I had done 2 programs so far, one for factorials and one for a Fibonacci number sequence. This problem has me stumped.

This is what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(m(i));
    }
}

public static double m(int i) {
    if (i == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return ???;
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What do you have so far?

Comment: @thegrinner updated it for ya.

Comment: As it's stated, this problem is not naturally suited to recursion.  However, it may be the case that the successive numerators follow a sequence with an easy recursive definition.  If that's true, then this isn't so much a programming problem as it is a math problem and you may have more luck on math.stackexchange.com.  If that's not true then this is a bad problem for understanding recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it looks like your base case is off - that should be 1/3 (the first number in the series).

For your else, you should return the next step down added to the current step. Given your series, the current step is `i/(2i + 1)`.

```
public static double m(int i) {
  if (i == 1) {
    // Base case is 1 - return the first number in the series
    return 1/3;
  } else {
    // Get the current step (ie the current iteration of m(i))
    double curStep = i / (2.0 * i + 1.0);

    // Return the current step plus the next step down
    return curStep + m(i - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the current step is? @thegrinner

Comment: @thegrinner You should probably add `.0` a few places to avoid integer division.

Comment: @BluceRee The current step happens to be the `i`th step in the series you have: `i/(2i + 1)`. For example, `m(1)` would become `1 / (2 * 1 + 1)`, or `1/3`. `m(5) = 5 / (2 * 5 + 1) = 5 / 11`. Also, I forgot the multiplication sign - fixing that in the answer.

Comment: For me this prints out 0.0 ten times. Also, thank you for the explanation.  @thegrinner

Comment: @BluceRee Make sure you have the `*` I forgot originally (should be `i / (2 * i + 1)`

Comment: You can actually condense this down further, since the base case is actually a reduction of the formula itself.

Comment: @BluceRee Also I was silly and had `int` instead of `double` - for small fractions like these it was rounding to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be recursive? if not, a simple for loop will do the trick.

```
double sum = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < i; x++)
{
    sum += x / (2.0 * x + 1);
}
return sum;
```

If it must be recursive, you need to start by properly identifying the base case. In this situation, your base case could be either 0 or 1. Examples:

Base case is 0:

```
public static double m(int i)
{
    if(i==0)
        return 0;
    else
    { 
        double sum = i/(2.0 * i + 1);

        return sum + m(i-1);
    }
}
```

Base case is 1:

```
public static double m(int i)
{
    if(i==1)
        return 1.0/3.0;
    else
    { 
        double sum = i/(2.0 * i + 1);

        return sum + m(i-1);
    }
}
```